# Fast methods to check linearity of differentials? Generalizing linearity? 

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

*The L1 Mat-1.1010 -course [here](https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-1.1010/etusivu) has taught me the linearity conditions $f(a x)=a f(x)$ and $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$. I want to generalize it, some quite irrelevant slow investigation [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/conversation/is-this-linear-i-think-no-some-fast-way-to-check-linearity).*

It requires time to verify statements like below, source [here](http://ocw.stut.edu.tw/file.php/14/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/%E8%AC%9B%E7%BE%A9/Ode1.pdf).

> [image]

According to Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation), $Ly=f$ and

> [image]

but I cannot see this kind of statements fast, unless going through the conditions one-by-one. So are there fast ways to check whether some differential is linear or not?

Comment: It's handy to remember that sums of linear operators are linear, so you can break stuff down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linear differential equation (of the second order) is of the form

$$a(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+b(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+c(x)y=d(x).$$

$y$ and its derivatives may not appear with a power or as the argument of a function.

Only $1.4$ fulfills this (with $a(x)=x^2,b(x)=0,c(x)=2,d(x)=2$).

The rule generalizes to all orders.

---

As you can check, with $z=\lambda y$ where $y$ is a solution,

$$a(x)\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+b(x)\frac{dz}{dx}+c(x)z=\lambda a(x)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\lambda b(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+\lambda c(x)y=\lambda d(x),$$

and with $z=y_1+y_2$ where $y_1,y_2$ are two solutions,

$$a(x)\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}+b(x)\frac{dz}{dx}+c(x)z\\
=a(x)\frac{d^2y_1}{dx^2}+b(x)\frac{dy_1}{dx}+c(x)y_1+a(x)\frac{d^2y_2}{dx^2}+b(x)\frac{dy_2}{dx}+c(x)y_2=2d(x),$$

so that in both cases $z$ is also a solution (provided you account for the factors in the RHS).

---

$1.5$ isn't linear because $z^2=(\lambda y)^2=\lambda^2y^2\ne\lambda y^2$.

$1.6$ isn't linear because $\sin z=\sin\lambda y\ne\lambda\sin y$.